# Wireshark: Show time in milliseconds?

Tags: wireshark

In Wireshark's UI, is it possible to display the time in milliseconds? I can find an option to show the timestamp with millisecond-precision, but not actually *in milliseconds*.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the "View" -> "Time Display Format" main menu option, which should affect all sorts of time columns you can have (I usually have relative time, delta time displayed and absolute time, at the same time)

Comment: This menu has a "milliseconds" option, but it only changes the display to have millisecond _precision_ as I mentioned in my original question. It does not seem to actually use milliseconds as the units.

Comment: That's correct, you cannot change the actual units after the capture is complete, just he display format. The precision of the timestamps in the capture file is set at capture time, by the capture PC/device. Most captures are taken with Microsecond precision on standard NICs, while nanosecond precision require special capture cards. If you only have milliseconds the precision is less than normal for a standard capture.

Comment: I think you misunderstand: the traces contain microsecond-level data. I want to view it in milliseconds. I think changing the units of display should be something supported, but perhaps it isn't.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem here. Either the trace does not have microsecond-level timestamps, so the display is correct. Or the trace has microsecond-level timestamps but doesn't show them (meaning you get "000" for microseconds if you set the column to display them), in which case you should open a bug report at https://bugs.wireshark.org

Comment: You can check the actual timestamp precision using "capinfos", which is a command line tool installed together with Wireshark. It will display a line saying "File timestamp precision:  microseconds" if the file has a microsecond-level precision.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, not sure if you already have the answer.
I got the same "Problem" recently, and figured out there is an option of "millisecond/microsecond/nanosecond" in View --> Time Display Format menu.
It was set to second by default.
Select millisecond, it'll show million second.